# PhoneGap app shows a strange documentation page on loading in mobile

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build

I am developing a phonegap app with the whole app is based in AngularJS. It works fine when I run it in the server but when I compile it over phonegap and run it in my android device. It shows a weird documentation page that comes from nowhere. I have attached the screenshot here. If anyone knows what's going on. Please point me in the right direction.

Screen shot of page when I run it in my android device:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Screen shot of page when I am running it in my web server:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: are you sure that both are same .And can you show me your code .

Comment: yes both are same, but which part of code do I show

Comment: Show me your Javascript index.js file .I want to see your document.ready functions and where you have bind events with document.ready.